# Usage tips in Bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, trial

Getting Started with Bluemix, what were your first applications using the platform? They could advise me? And forgive anything for the question.

Thank you for attention.

Comment: I'm sorry, it's not clear what you are actually asking?

Answer (score 2):

I think it depends on what is your programming experience and your personal preference. If you want to begin programming with the classic Object-Oriented paradigm you should try Liberty runtime. Instead if you like the scripting languages maybe you could give a try to Python, Ruby or Go runtimes. All of them provide a sample application that you can extend as you want, and have very detailed documentation. I suggest you to take a look at IBM Containers, they are very interesting and powerful, and they make you able to do potentially anything with the platform.

If you come from the on-premise world, please notice that Bluemix is built on Cloud Foundry, and there are two important considerations to think about:

- **Local file system storage is short-lived**. When an application instance crashes or stops, the resources assigned to that instance are reclaimed by the platform including any local disk changes made since the app started. When the instance is restarted, the application will start with a new disk image. *Although your application can write local files while it is running, the files will disappear after the application restarts*.
- **Instances of the same application do not share a local file system**. Each application instance runs in its own isolated container. Thus *if your application needs the data in the files to persist across application restarts, or the data needs to be shared across all running instances of the application, the local file system should not be used.*

For this reason local file system ***should not be used***.

Personally since I had some experience in JEE + WAS my first application was a Web app developed on Liberty Runtime.
I suggest you to become familiar with [IBM Bluemix DevOps Services](https://hub.jazz.net/), that allows you to develop, build and deploy working on a web IDE.

Answer (score 1):

So the various runtimes and services within bluemix provide 2 types of samples to help you get started.  Boilerplate, which are samples you can extend to develop new applications  and there is a "deploy to bluemix" button on other samples which can be used to automatically get the sample installed and ready to try.  What you start with is usually something like this to see it working and then go from there.

Answer (score 1):

This question already has been answered in a way. But I think what you are looking for are the types of applications you can develop using Bluemix.

To directly answer your question - the first application I developed used the **Concept Insights** Watson service to extract insights from some news articles and create a concept based news search. I also experimented with **Language Translation** service where-in I converted the contents of a web page from English to Spanish.

If you look through the documentation pages for the various Watson services, you would come across various use cases where a particular service is applicable.

On a more general note I can see that Bluemix would help us to write some really **smart** applications in an easy way. The Watson Services provide a real simple interface to all application developers by taking away the highly complex tasks of machine learning and AI algorithms which would need a good level of expertise if done on our own.

Additionally, Bluemix is just like any other PaaS for e.g AWS or Google Compute Engine or Azure. Bluemix does provide relational databases, queues, time series database containers etc as a part of the platform. These would need to be used by the application that you are developing to cater to use cases of inter-process communication, data storage etc.

Hopefully this answer provides you some insight on what applications you can write with the Bluemix concept insight services

Answer (score -1):

Our local applications run on WAS ND. When we moved to trying Liberty on BlueMix(as application, not service), typical problems were mostly around [12 Factors](http://12factor.net/).

1. Config && Dev/Prod parity --> Earlier our configurations were in files inside application or configured in WAS. With Liberty, we were forced to externalize that and it was easy to setup environment variables in BlueMix.
2. Process --> As state-fullness was no longer an option, we had to change our application to store session outside, in relational as well as document DB.
3. Logs --> Logs are not available in local logs files as earlier.
4. Ephemeral instances --> As mentioned by [Umberto](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33973152/6317694)